# Why is the .try method terminating my program?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am capturing a string date from params that should be in the form of YYYY-DD-MM. If the parameter is an invalid date, I want `nil` to be assigned to `minimum`. Like if the param was 2013-40-50 for example. I am able to do so successfully with :

`minimum = Date.try(:parse, (params[:newer_than])) if params[:newer_than].present?`

If the date is of the correct format, it is assigned to `minimum`, otherwise `nil` is. However, in the case where it is `nil`, the program terminates and I get ArgumentError - invalid date.

The whole idea of me using `.try` is that if it in fact fails, it's okay, move along. I am handling the case if it were nil afterward. The error is thrown on the line assigning to `minimum`.

How can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rescue` for your goal:

```
minimum = begin
  Date.parse(params[:newer_than])
rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
  nil
end
```

According to [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try), `try` just like the regular Ruby Object#send if methos defined on object, so it does not prevent errors like `ArgumentError` and `TypeError`.

Answer (score 2):

It's the way you're using the call.

The `try` call is not like a begin/rescue.  It just tries to call the function if it exists on that object.  If the function does not exist, no biggie, it won't call the function and just proceed.  Otherwise, it calls it and works as it normally would.

In this case, calling `try` does you no good, as you know for sure that function exists for date.  What's happening is the `parse` function is throwing an error.

What you should do instead is go ahead and call `Date.parse` within a begin/rescue block, and catch those particular errors (ArgumentError) that could be thrown by the `parse` function.  You could also pre-validate the string (using regex, for example) to ensure it's in the proper format before calling parse.

Either way, `parse` does not do any validation for you, so either you can check it before hand or begin/rescue the errors it throws.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies